# how do i do more operations in create() method of RegisterController.php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i can't do any more operations in create() method of `RegisterController.php` since it returns right after the user is created , i also don't have `AuthController.php` in my files ( although i have ran `php artisan make:auth` , but its missing .

NOTE : i need to do more operation , because i have another table called logs , i want to pass the id of the user created , but it can't be done , as i said in `create()` method it returns and don't let me do anymore operation .
i don't want to wright a function myself , i use remember token and other benefits . how do i do it then ? my code :  protected function create(array 
    $data)
    {
        $v = new Verta();

```
    // REMEMBER TO CREATE THEM IN MIGRATIONS

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'family' => $data['family'],
        'national_code' => $data['national_code'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'birth_date' => $v->formatDate(),
        'username' =>$data['username'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),// REMEMBER TO CREATE THEM IN MIGRATIONS
        'cell_phone' => $data['cell_phone'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'created_at_shamsi' => $v->formatDate()
    ]);

    Logs::create([
    'logDate' => $v->formatDate(),
    'logTime' => $v->formatTime(),
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'logCode' => '010',
    'log_desc' => 'حساب با موفقیت ایجاد شد'
    ]);



}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Can anyone answer this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `RegisterConntroller`, add the log before the returning the `User` object.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    // create your logs here, Log::create($user->id);

    return $user;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Events`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events) to insert the log whenever an user is created. From the docs:

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into the
>   following points in a model's lifecycle: retrieved, creating, created,
>   updating, updated, saving, saved,  deleting, deleted, restoring,
>   restored. Events allow you to easily execute code each time a specific
>   model class is saved or updated in the database.

Comment: OK , i will do as you said .

Comment: $user->id will have your newly created user's id

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. (easy way) Modify the `create` function, such that:

   ```
   protected function create(array $data)
   {
       $user = User::create([
           'name' => $data['name'],
           'email' => $data['email'],
           'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
       ]);

       // DO YOUR LOG HERE

       return $user;
   }
   ```
2. Or, cleaner way, listen to the event and execute it when model was created:

   a. Create Observers `app/Observers/UserObserver.php` ([Read more about observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers))

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Observers;

   use App\User;

   class UserObserver
   {
       public function created(User $user)
       {
           // PUT YOUR LOG HERE
       }
   }
   ```

   b. Register your observer at `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Providers;

   use App\User;
   use App\Observers\UserObserver;
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
       /**
        * Bootstrap any application services.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function boot()
       {
           User::observe(UserObserver::class);
       }

       /**
        * Register the service provider.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function register()
       {
           //
       }
   }
   ```
3. Or, register events, let the model emit event, and catch it from your listeners and execute logging there. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events)